# Unity sprite fade in and out speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to loop a fade-in and fade-out of a sprite in unity. I am new to Unity and C#.

My current code:

```
public float minimum = 0.0f;
public float maximum = 1f;
public float duration = 50.0f;

public bool faded = false;

private float startTime;
public SpriteRenderer sprite;

void Start () {
    startTime = Time.time;
}

void Update () {
    float t = (Time.time - startTime) / duration;

    if (faded) {
        sprite.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.SmoothStep(minimum, maximum, t));
        if (t > 1f) {
            faded = false;
            startTime = Time.time;
        }
    } else {
        sprite.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.SmoothStep(maximum, minimum, t));
        if (t > 1f) {
            faded = true;
            startTime = Time.time;
        }
    }
}
```

This works but it is too slow, I wish to make the fade in faster and the fade out a bit slower than the fade in. Something of the effect of a heartbeat. How do I update my code for that?

Also, is there a better approach to this? I think i'll get a memory leak with the too much `NEW` on the `Update()`.

As for what Andrew has given, I tried to debug his code:

```
    } else {
        sprite.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.Lerp(sprite.color.a, minimum, step));
        print (Mathf.Abs(sprite.color.a - minimum));
        print (threshold);
```

Shows me:

```
 2.206551E-20 // Mathf.Abs()?
 1.401298E-45 // threshold?
```

Comment: @Sayse, I did try setting the duration lower, something like `5f` but it didn't do much difference, I think it didn't do any at all.

Comment: `2.206551E-20 // Mathf.Abs() == 00000000000000000002206551`
`1.401298E-45 // threshold == 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001401298`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont worry about the `new` in the `Update()`, because `Color` is a value type, and `C#` is good at handling garbage collection

```
public float minimum = 0.0f;
public float maximum = 1f;
public float speed = 5.0f;
public float threshold = float.Epsilon;

public bool faded = false;

public SpriteRenderer sprite;

void Update () {
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (faded) {
        sprite.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.Lerp(sprite.color.a, maximum, step));
        if (Mathf.Abs(maximum - sprite.color.a) <= threshold)
            faded = false;

    } else {
        sprite.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.Lerp(sprite.color.a, minimum, step));
        if (Mathf.Abs(sprite.color.a - minimum) <= threshold)
            faded = true;
    }
}
```

Also, if all you care about is a fade in-out effect, all you need is a single line:

```
public float max = 1f;
public float speed = 5.0f;

public SpriteRenderer sprite;

void Update () {
    sprite.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, max));
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see thanks for clearing that up. But the code you've provided, it faded the sprite but it never came back. Also I replaced, `float.epsilon` with `float.Epsilon`. Had an error the the lowercase one.

Comment: try increasing the threshold to like `0.001f`

Comment: I'll try to experiment with this, but so far that updated threshold still doesn't make the sprite show back again (fade-in).

Comment: yea no prob, also i updated for a second way of achieving it

Comment: thanks man, I also updated my question. Just to give a few context on why its not coming back (fade-in). Also, I need it to have a heartbeat effect. So the fade-in is a bit faster than the fade-out. Would the 1-liner work with that?

Comment: The 1-liner looks nice but its too fast, how do I make it slower?

Comment: change the speed variable to something smaller, like 1 or so, and no, i dont think you can easily do the heart rate effect with the `PingPong` one

Comment: 1 did it, I did try to edit it on the script to 1 but it didnt change anything. So i tried to change it on the inspector view and it did. Why is that?

Comment: Ohh because the inspector remembers public variables, you have to always remember that it goes to the last setting if its public, even if you update it in script