# Fading Alpha Values In Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am making a game for Android using Unity 5.4.0f3 and am having trouble fading out a sprite's `color.a` value. I have tried animations, but they don't seem to work for me. I have tried using the code from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/225438/slowly-fades-from-opaque-to-alpha.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459146/unity-sprite-fade-in-and-out-speed), but those didn't work either. I want the sprite to fade out over about 1 second when it is tapped. I think I need to use a `for` loop and `Mathf.Lerp`. Please help.

Edit: Here is an image of the Inspector view of the object I want to fade out.

[image]

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the material the object has attached, especially its shader type.

Comment: Added image to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Sprite-Default` material is **NOT** modifiable.

Try this instead:

> **Easiest way:**

```
/* Modify SpriteRenderer.color instead of Material.color */ 
//Get the renderer via GetComponent or have it cached previously
var renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
renderer.color = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f); // Do your lerping stuff with this property
```

> **If you still want to modify Material**

1. Create a new material in `Project` tab and name it whatever you
   want. `Project` tab -> `Create` -> `Material`.

   [image]
2. Assign it a shader like in the below image.

   [image]
3. Assign the newly created `material` to your Sprite Renderer
   `Material` slot. Notice that now you can modify material color from
   the inspector. It has not been grayed out any more. You should run
   you code again and it should work.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure change sprRender.color, not color.a. Simple code for you, Fadeout worked. Add your advanced.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]

public class FadeOut : MonoBehaviour {
    SpriteRenderer sprRender;

    void Start()
    {
        sprRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        sprRender.color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Geo Wesley, this worked for me, not sure why you didn't get flagged the answer, but take my vote!